# Raid 0 nvme disk configuration is slower

Tags: mysql, raid

I installed MySQL db for storing my simulation data in phd. First I used a pc with i7-8700 cpu, 24 gb ram and 1 TB nvme disk.

Then I transferred data to a newer pc with i7-12700 cpu, 48 GB ram and 2x1 nvme 1 TB disk in soft raid0 configuration. Since then my query performance become very slow. It was 10-15 minutes in old pc to 2.5 hours on the newer hardware. I configured the conf file according to new hardware but nothing changed. Any ideas please. I am desperate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` show?

Comment: Please provide a specific example of a much slower query.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Additional DB information request from EACH PC - old and new -, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.  From each PC - OLD and NEW. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

Considering you have already adjusted the 'conf' file to your new hardware. You might want to ensure that your tables are still properly indexed. If you're running queries they may have changed during the transfer.

I would also make sure you're monitoring the disk performance as you have raid0 config. Your disk can always be a bottleneck, especially if something is not configured right. Please check your raid0 config and ensure it is set appropriately.